# Just Read and Write a file in C# corrupts the data

Tags: c#, file

I would be very happy if someone can help me to solve this problem. I have a file with some data in it which I am not sure but I guess the data format is UFT8 and I am reading it in C# and without any change writing it back into the file but then the data in the file becomes corrupted.

Here is my file output from NotePad++ with UTF8 encoding:
[image]

Then I am reading it and with no change writing it back into the file but when I reopen it in the NotePad++ I see this output:
[image]

Here is my read and write code written in C#:

```
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fs = new FileStream(path + name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    MyTextBox.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}

private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path + name + ".modified", FileMode.Create));
    bw.Write(BytesToString(buffer));
    bw.Close();
}

static string BytesToString(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BinaryWriter handles strings specially, it writes extra bytes so BinaryReader.ReadString() has a shot at correctly figuring out the string length.  You see those back as wonky characters.  Just don't use FileStream, StreamReader/Writer get the job done.  They have constructors that accept an Encoding.

Comment: StreamReader/Writer has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found where was my problem. In fact I am reading the file in binary but when I am writing it back I am converting the binary to string and the causes the problem. So if I just use the below code, all will work fine because during the writing it will not convert binary to string:

```
private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
  var bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path + name + ".modified", FileMode.Create));
        bw.Write(buffer);}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use [Stream Reader](https://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader) or [Stream Writer](https://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter) instead.